# LDAP Connect using Java and search for Duplicate profiles

Tags: java, ldap

I am trying to implement functionality where you can search LDAP for duplicate profiles of members and remove it.

I found some APIs for connecting to LDAP using Java. But which API can do this search? We have this functionality in Softterra LDAP browser to write query and search.

- OpenLDAP LDAP SDK
- Mozilla Directory
- Apache Directory API

Comment: Small spelling fixes.

Comment: All of them, and also JNDI of course. Off topic.

Comment: Yes we can connect but how fetch duplicate user principal names ?